# WordPress 500 Error with wp_mail

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress, email

Im trying to send data from AngularJS to a PHP file and using the PHP to send an email with wp_mail but Im getting a 500 error and I cant seem to figure out where Im going wrong. I seem to be sending the data in a correct format to the PHP file, but Im just getting an error response.

AngularJS Call

```
$scope.sendEmail = function() {
            if ($scope.resultsTitle) {
                $scope.resultsTitle = $scope.resultsTitle;
            }
            else if ($scope.resultsTitle == "") {
                $scope.resultsTitle = "Survey Not Completed";
            }
              $scope.userData = {
                "userEmail": $scope.email,
                "todaysDate": $scope.date,
                "timeNow": $scope.time,
                "question1": $scope.question1Answer.toString(),
                "question2": $scope.question2Answer.toString(),
                "question3": $scope.question3Answer.toString(),
                "question4": $scope.question4Answer.toString(),
                "question5": $scope.question5Answer.toString(),
                "question6": $scope.question6Answer.toString(),
                "question7": $scope.question7Answer.toString(),
                "question8": $scope.question8Answer.toString(),
                "question9": $scope.question9Answer.toString(),
                "question10": $scope.question10Answer.toString(),
                "endResult": $scope.resultsTitle
              };
              $log.info($scope.userData);


                $http({
                      method: 'POST',
                      url: 'mailer.php',
                      data: $scope.userData
                  })
                  .then(function successCallback(response) {
                            $log.log("Sent to PHP file!");
                            $log.log(response);
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                            $log.log("Data not sent to the php file!")
                            $log.warn(response);
                    });
        };
```

PHP Mailer File:

```
<?php
 $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $user_email = $request->userEmail;
    $todays_date = $request->todaysDate;
    $time = $request->timeNow;
    $question1 = $request->question1;
    $question2 = $request->question2;
    $question3 = $request->question3;
    $question4 = $request->question4;
    $question5 = $request->question5;
    $question6 = $request->question6;
    $question7 = $request->question7;
    $question8 = $request->question8;
    $question9 = $request->question9;
    $question10 = $request->question10;
    $endResult = $request->endResult;


$message = "
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>The Title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Thank you.</p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Your Email</th>
                    <th>Today's Date</th>
                    <th>The Current Time</th>
                    <th>Question 1</th>
                    <th>Question 2</th>
                    <th>Question 3</th>
                    <th>Question 4</th>
                    <th>Question 5</th>
                    <th>Question 6</th>
                    <th>Question 7</th>
                    <th>Question 8</th>
                    <th>Question 9</th>
                    <th>Question 10</th>
                    <th>End Decision</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$user_email</td>
                    <td>$todays_date</td>
                    <td>$time</td>
                    <td>$question1</td>
                    <td>$question2</td>
                    <td>$question3</td>
                    <td>$question4</td>
                    <td>$question5</td>
                    <td>$question6</td>
                    <td>$question7</td>
                    <td>$question8</td>
                    <td>$question9</td>
                    <td>$question10</td>
                    <td>$endResult</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
";

    echo ($user_email, 'The Subject', $message);
    return wp_mail($user_email, 'The Subject', $message);

?>
```

Comment: Note that Im using MAMP for my local version and Windows IIS7 for the prod version.

Comment: You need to check your error_log file. Or enable display_errors to see what the wrong is.

Comment: The easy way to check what's wrong is by toggling pieces of code, I would comment out from `$postdata` to the end of  `echo` and just put your email plus a random message and see if that's working. If it sends the email the problem is somewhere in the commented block, if it doesn't, there's something wrong when you try to send an email. Maybe some error logs could help us more as suggested above!

Comment: Also as a side note, a PHP script should not `return` at the end. Best practice is to echo if you really want to. Maybe do something like `$result = wp_mail($user_email...);` and then an if/else on the `$result` where on true you `echo 'success';` and when false `echo 'something went wrong';` or something like that! :D

Comment: Thank you both very much! Turned on PHP errors and found where I had gone wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

All,

The solution ended up being adjusting in mailer:

```
Changed return wp_mail to wp_mail
Deleted echo wp_mail

Added $parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' ); to the top of the file
```

Comment: I can't understand anything from answer . Please edit your answer to better explain exactly how you fixed it.. which file *exactly* did you edit?